# LLVM build failure in dynamic-regmask.ll

Tags: unit-testing, build, llvm

I am trying to build LLVM from source in Lubuntu 16.04.

I followed the instructions from

> http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html

and I run cmake for Unix Makefiles and then make check-all with the default options.

After building everything it run the unittests and I am getting an unexpected failure in llvm/test/CodeGen/MIR/X86/dynamic-regmask.ll

The error is:

```
FAIL: LLVM :: CodeGen/MIR/X86/dynamic-regmask.ll (1 of 1)
******************** TEST 'LLVM :: CodeGen/MIR/X86/dynamic-regmask.ll' FAILED ********************
Script:
--
llc -stop-after machine-sink /home/------/llvm/llvm/test/CodeGen/MIR/X86/dynamic-regmask.ll -o /home/--------/llvm/build/test/CodeGen/MIR/X86/Output/dynamic-regmask.ll.tmp.mir
FileCheck /home/--------/llvm/llvm/test/CodeGen/MIR/X86/dynamic-regmask.ll < /home/-------/llvm/build/test/CodeGen/MIR/X86/Output/dynamic-regmask.ll.tmp.mir
llc /home/--------/llvm/build/test/CodeGen/MIR/X86/Output/dynamic-regmask.ll.tmp.mir -run-pass machine-sink
--
Exit Code: 1

Command Output (stderr):
--
/home/--------/llvm/llvm/test/CodeGen/MIR/X86/dynamic-regmask.ll:14:10: error: expected string not found in input
; CHECK: CALL64pcrel32 @callee, CustomRegMask(%bh,%bl,%bp,%bpl,%bx,%ebp,%ebx,%esp,%rbp,%rbx,%rsp,%sp,%spl,%r10,%r11,%r12,%r13,%r14,%r15,%xmm8,%xmm9,%xmm10,%xmm11,%xmm12,%xmm13,%xmm14,%xmm15,%r10b,%r11b,%r12b,%r13b,%r14b,%r15b,%r10d,%r11d,%r12d,%r13d,%r14d,%r15d,%r10w,%r11w,%r12w,%r13w,%r14w,%r15w)
         ^
<stdin>:34:1: note: scanning from here
alignment: 4
^

--

********************
Testing Time: 0.53s
********************
Failing Tests (1):
    LLVM :: CodeGen/MIR/X86/dynamic-regmask.ll
```

Does anyone know what to do to fix this?

Is this a type of problem that I should file a bug report on LLVM? I checked their website and it looks like the bug reports are for usage of LLVM instead of building LLVM.

Can someone at least point me to a resource that is going to help me understand what the test files are supposed to do?